# string variable in if statment fail

Tags: java

so I try to use a string variable in the if statement but it seems it doesn't work like int and double and other primitive data types, why? Pls help
my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Something{
   static void Some(){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String answer;
      
      System.out.println("Hello Sir, what can I do for you?");
      answer = input.nextLine();
      
      String i = "2";
      
      if(answer == i){
         System.out.println("Sure Sir ");
      }
      
      else{
         System.out.println("Sir, anything?");
      }
   }


   public static void main(String [] args){
      Some();
   }
}
```

input:2
output: Sir, anything?

Comment: In short: `if(answer.equals(i))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator compares references in case of strings. To compare values you can use `equals()` method.

```
if(a.equals(b)){}
```